# Census badge description is not used in localization engine

Tags: bug, status-norepro, localization, stack-overflow-developer-survey

Looks like the “Census” badge name and its description are not used in localized engine. I.e. as far as I see all sentences have been translated at least two months ago, but not used on site. E.g. screenshots from Stack Overflow in Russian:

> [image: After the survey completed]
>
> [image: Achivement notification in inbox]
>
> [image: Badge description]

<s>I’m pretty sure that same behavior occurs for other non-English sites.</s> Other sites (pt, es, ja) have full or partial translation for this badge, hence current bug report should be moved to ruSO.meta probably, but I still can’t understand the reason why translation is not used from Transifex.

P.S. apologizes for using [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) tag on MSE.

Comment: It kind-of makes sense because it's a *Developer Survey*, not an *опрос программистов*.

Comment: The "and supplied your profile URL" part is no longer needed since this year the survey automatically redirects you to a page which makes you earn the badge without you having to supply any URL.

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, how do you earn the Census badge on Russian Stack Overflow? Do you complete the same survey but in Russian?

Comment: @DonaldDuck I pressed a link from the banner appeared on ruSO.

Comment: @DonaldDuck We have the same survey in English for all Stack Overflows.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky so the link contains the referring site?

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard Seems like it. After passing the survey I got the badge on Stack Overflow in Russian where I'd clicked on the banner.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky I see. So can you please answer [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305525/in-which-site-among-stack-overflow-localized-sites-is-the-census-badge-awarded) with that info? (Coming from you, it will appear more official than someone else.)

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard In this case I am as official as any other user :) I might know the right person to ask.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Census badge [has been permanently retired and retroactively revoked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424491/removal-of-the-census-badge) from all users on all sites.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog do we really need to close old question that is obsolete now? What's the benefit we can get doing that?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ it will still remain here since it has an (upvoted?) answer, and be able to receive votes, but not get new answers (which is appropriate). Plus, it will give a signal that this is no longer of any significance.

Comment: @Joachim should we then close all other obsolete/fixed/not-reproduced etc questions?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Except for fixes for situations that are still applicable, that is the general idea, yes :)

Comment: **Update:** Gonna have to mea culpa on this one. After this got closed, the team decided to re-award the Census badge to users who previously earned it (only once so the same privacy concerns no longer apply). As such, voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks fixed now. The problem possibly was on the Transifex side, or/and cache-related:

> [image: badge info]

Some extra discussion can be found in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42170062#42170062) (be careful: Russians inside).